# MySQL root password changed by someone or app self

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, hacking, exploit

I have a server that is accessible to the public, but i've been 3 times I was in the locker MySQL root password by someone else, who knows the password that's only me. I've checked on the server disk I not find php injection and the like, and I already turned off the function exec in php like passthru, exec, shell_exec, etc.

On server using Ubuntu 10.04 Server and fresh Install OS, MySSQL Ver 14:14 Distrib 5.5.17, Nginx, php5-fpm.

My question is: 
Is there a app that can changed MySQL root password by cron/job in Ubuntu Server?.

Thanks.

Comment: For security reasons mysql should not be accessible from the Internet. As you run php and nginx on the same server, you should restrict mysql connection to 127.0.0.1 and local socket.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reset your mysql server password by going into safe mode please follow this link http://24x7servermanagement.com/blog/?p=44
I hope this will help you.

Comment: Please read our [faq] in particular [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://serverfault.com/faq#promotion).